# Smarty Modifiers PHP

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to get Smarty setup and working, so that I can install the open-source project here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/assign-calc/

After following the install instructions, I get stuck with the following error message

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template &quot;/var/www/dev/calendar/skins/rpc/tmpl/page/rpc_header.tpl&quot;  on line 5 &quot;         {$application.long_name|escape}&quot; unknown modifier &quot;escape&quot;' in /usr/lib/php5/Smarty/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:423
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/lib/php5/Smarty/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_private_modifier.php(62): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase-&gt;trigger_template_error('unknown modifie...', 5)
#1 /usr/lib/php5/Smarty/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(279): Smarty_Internal_Compile_Private_Modifier-&gt;compile(Array, Object(Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler), Array, NULL, NULL)
#2 /usr/lib/php5/Smarty/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(123): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase-&gt;callTagCompiler('private_modifie...', Array, Array)
#3 /usr/lib/php5/Smarty/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_private_print_expression.php(68): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase in <b>/usr/lib/php5/Smarty/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php</b> on line <b>423</b><br />
```

After a bit of googling, I think the problem is being cause by Smarty not reading the escape modifier in the plugins directory.

How do I resolve this? I've even tried 777 the permissions on smarty, but that hasnt change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you loaded the smarty configuration correctly? In particular, have you setted correctly the plugin path, through the command

```
$smarty->addPluginsDir('path/to/plugins');
```

?

Comment: I havent, but what I am using is a clean install of Smarty, and a clean install of assign-calc. Based on smarty not being set in the config file (for assign-calc), I think its fair to assume to that this folder should be loaded automatically (at least it should based on the Smarty documentation I have seen...  Where would you recommend I place this line

Comment: You can find best practice on the Smarty documentation. However, you're right, a clean installation should load default plugins correctly. Perhaps assign-calc makes itself some configuration on the smarty engine?

Comment: For the time being I added in your line of code and it seems to be working, but I am still open for answers as to why its not detecting this automatically in the first place, since I beleive its poor practice to hardcode a file's absolute path especially when it will be moved to another server

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of the Research Project Calculator, and found this SO question while researching the same problem for another user.  The code has only been in the wild for a few weeks and we're discovering some of these things as other institutions install it.

I was able to get it running for the other user by explicitly calling `parent::__construct();` before anything else in the inc/rpc_smarty.inc.php class constructor. I'll post a new release shortly, but for now you should just be able to patch that constructor as below.

Please feel free to contact me via the link in the project's installation instructions wiki page if you have more questions or run into other problems.

```
public function __construct($config)
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->config = $config;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An absolute system path is the fastest and safest approach. You can use relative paths, but be certain the php include_path contains what is needed to find it. You could also use SMARTY_DIR to base your path from.